# c# WPF Threading an OnResponse event to MainWindowViewModel from singleton object

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

Greetings my smart programming friends!

I have created an OnResponseEvent for an object that is injected into my viewmodel via UnityContainer.

From my injected object class:

```
    public delegate void ResponseEventHandler(AbstractResponse response);

    public event ResponseEventHandler OnResponseEvent;

Constructor for MainWindowViewModel:

public MainWindowViewModel(ITrack track)
        {
            this._track = Track;
            track.OnResponseEvent += UpdateTrackResponseWindow;
        }
```

Created delegate to handle the OnResponseEvent in my MainWindowViewModel:

```
private delegate void HandleTrackResponseCallback(AbstractResponse message);
```

Since the OnResponseEvent is sending a message, I need to interpret the message in a separate thread and display in a listBox.
Here is where I get confused.  If I were using WinForms to write this application, I could use the following code because WinForms knows about my listBox:

```
 if (ListBox.InvokeRequired)
    {
        var d = new HandleTrackResponseCallback(UpdateTrackResponseWindow);
        Invoke(d, new object[] { message });
    }
    else
        lstTrackResponse.Text = Interpret(message);  //Interpret is a separate method
```

However, I am using WPF, and my MainWindowViewModel class does not know anything about my listBox which is located in a view.

Can anyone provide example code how I might handle the OnResponseEvent on a different thread in my MainWindowViewModel class?

Thanks so much, any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Manipulating the view from the view-model goes against the basic architectural principles of MVVM.  Even if it weren't a being called from a different thread it would still not be a wise thing to do.

In MVVM, you would handle this like you do any other data that needs to be displayed in the view:

- process and store the data in the view-model itself (using your event handler)
- expose it as property including change notification
- access that property **from the view** using traditional data binding

Something as simple as:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Response}"/>
```

This approach even takes care of the threading problem because now you handle the concurrency issues in the view-model, instead of in the view.  Just lock access to the property that `TextBox.Text` is bound to while you are modifying it.

In general, MVVM avoids ever having a direct dependency of the view-model on the view for several reasons:

- the big picture goal of loose-coupling between the view-model and the view
- the ability to **unit test** the view-model **without a view**

At first this separation might seem clumsy and requires extra work (see above) but it really is worth it and it's what we need to do to get the benefits of the MVVM approach.